# Landsat 5 missing archives in Africa

Tags: landsat, satellite, usgs, landsat-5, earth-explorer

I am trying to download Landsat 5 tile on USGS explorer from the  Landsat Collection 1 and Landsat Collection 2 dataset in order to do temporal analysis.
However, in Africa, I can only retrieve a few images between 1984 and 2002 (approximately one every two year). In other continent such as Europe, I can access all images (every 14 days).

Is it a USGS issue, or can I get the data somewhere else ?

PS : I am posting my issue here because `custserv@usgs.gov` has not answering to me.

Comment: If this is open data then a place you may be able to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer